# This summer on our city is very hot or This summer is very hot in our city?

Tags: word-order

This summer in our city is very hot
or
This summer is very hot in our city

Which sentence is more correct?
I believe that the both sentences are correct, but I perfer to use the second one

Do this sentences have different meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Both the sentences you've provided aren't natural ways to say what you're trying to say since in both cases you're saying the summer, as a season, itself is hot as opposed to the weather during summer, if that makes any sense.
You could try:

> It's very hot in our city this summer.

or even

> This summer, it is very hot in our city.